# Docker build fails with GPG error: NO_PUBKEY 1A127079A92F09ED

Tags: docker, gnupg, ubuntu-20.04, apt, keyserver

I am trying to build Docker on an existing RPI Docker image - which worked fine until recently. It fails when trying to run apt-get update.

The full error is:

> GPG error: https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1A127079A92F09ED

After wandering around in [Stack Overflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) and other [sites](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkvovuVpA0Q), I found that the two most common solutions are:

1. Get the key from a repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <PUBKEY>
   ```

   which didn't work in my case - I tried several repositories and all returned:

   ```
   gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
   ```
2. Update Docker (I am already updated).

Per request, following is the basic Dockerfile I am using which is built on top of [ros:foxy](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ros/foxy/images/sha256-07284f6fda4137bcf00d11a15f884c92b69b8b13b11eed51861a36f90265ffd5?context=explore):

```
FROM ros:foxy
ENV SHELL /bin/bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV MAKEFLAGS="-j 1"
ENV LOCAL_WS=/ros2_ws

#Following are some attempts I made which didn't work:
#RUN sh -c 'curl -fsSL https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg'  
#RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list
#RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys 1A127079A92F09ED 
#    && gpg --export 1A127079A92F09ED | apt-key add -


RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gdb vim

........
```

What else can I try?

Trying to build Docker and failing on apt-get update due to missing Ubuntu 20.04 keys.

Comment: Could you supply the `Dockerfile` you are using, and also a link to the `FROM` image (by editing the question)?

Comment: @halfer I added the basic Dockerfile and a link to the docker image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the following line, before apt-get update:

```
RUN wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | tee /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
```

Comment: Initially I thought it was odd that it needed this, but I spotted that the APT key it needs is from a non-Ubuntu source. Perhaps the original Dockerfile also uses a key from kitware.com, but that one is no longer valid, and so you have to take an additional step to correct it.

Comment: Seems like it. thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: @AibohphobiA `tee: /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg: Permission denied`

Comment: @Bilal Add `sudo` before the `tee` command. `sudo` isn't required when building a Docker container. However, I searched for this error but I am not using Docker. This was the first post that came up. Doing the above command generated `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.` I searched through the Ask Ubuntu forums and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1389758/572920). I used that command but swapped out the key with the one in question (seen in the OP's title): `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1A127079A92F09ED`. After executing this command, it now works.